# Unable to submit form to database in custom module

Tags: blocks, 8

I am building a custom module and I'm unable to get the form to talk to the database. The section for uploading to the file system works fine.

This is MyModuleBlock.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\my_module;

/**
 *  @Block(
 *    id = "my_module",
 *    admin_label = @Translation("Add Image"),
 *  )
 */

class ImageBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
      // stuff here;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $form['image'] = array(
      '#title' => t('My Module'),
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location'=> 'public://images/',
      '#required' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      "#type" => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Upload',
    );

    return $form;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  public function submitForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      MyModuleDB::add();
  }
}
```

The MyModuleDB.php (I am trying out plain text to see if any errors or anything pops up):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

class MyModuleDB {
    static function add(){
        db_insert('my_table')
            ->fields(array('image' => 'img1'
            ))->execute();
    }
}
```

I'm at a total loss here. The tutorials I've found claim that this should work out fine, but it isn't working for me at all. I even tried inserting into the database directly from submitForm() in the main block class. I also tried to add redirects to the submitForm(). I'm thinking the issue is in that function, but I don't see what the issue could be.

Comment: There's a lot here that doesn't make sense. If you have a block then you are not supposed to save anything yourself somewhere in the database. Anything that is part of the block configuration just needs to be added to $this->configuration in blockSubmit() as mentioned by Daniel Wehner.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to Drupal, so yeah, I'm sure quite a bit won't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a block, use `\Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface::blockSubmit` for submission

Answer (score 2):

What your `submitForm()` should do is shown from [`AggregatorFeedBlock::blockSubmit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21AggregatorFeedBlock.php/function/AggregatorFeedBlock%3A%3AblockSubmit/8), for example.

```
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->configuration ['block_count'] = $form_state->getValue('block_count');
  $this->configuration ['feed'] = $form_state->getValue('feed');
}
```

See the code of [`AggregatorFeedBlock::blockForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21AggregatorFeedBlock.php/function/AggregatorFeedBlock%3A%3AblockForm/8) too.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $feeds = $this->feedStorage->loadMultiple();
  $options = array();
  foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    $options [$feed->id()] = $feed->label();
  }
  $form ['feed'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Select the feed that should be displayed'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration ['feed'],
    '#options' => $options,
  );
  $range = range(2, 20);
  $form ['block_count'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Number of news items in block'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration ['block_count'],
    '#options' => array_combine($range, $range),
  );
  return $form;
}
```